# Setting Linux IP with C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, networking, ipv4

I am trying to find a way that I can effectively change the IP and netmask of the computer that my programs are running on.  I have to be able to maintain communications with a "box" that the user has access to and can change the IP of that box (but not that of the Linux host).  Luckily the box broadcasts its IP over a multicast address.  I am able to read that address and communicate to whatever IP the box is broadcasting.  However, my problem is that when the box changes IPs outside of the subnet of the Linux host, I lose connectivity (as I would expect to happen).

As a result, I need a quick and dirty way to to change the IP and netmask of the Linux host when it detects that the IP being broadcast is outside it's subnet.  I am aware that I can modify/edit the /etc/networking/interfaces file, but I was hoping to have something "live" where I wouldn't need to restart the networking interface or Linux host.  Additionally, I would like to maintain all sockets that I have currently open during the change.  My main issue is that I have a slew of connections run by other applications that cannot be corrupted as a result of the IP changeover.  Also, if possible, I'd like to avoid having to redo having to run the multicast route add command for Linux after the host IP changeover.

Is there anything that I can do to satisfy these requirements?  Thanks.

Comment: If you want to maintain current connections, it may be best to ensure you have two NICs in the Linux box, one unchanging one for regular traffic and one you can continuously morph to communicate with the elusive box.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Linux host system in question is an embedded system with only the capacity for one NIC.  I don't necessarily want to maintain the connection DURING the changeover, but I would need all sockets to retain connectivity afterwards.  I want to avoid having to find a way to send a falg to all my open sockets that they need to reinitialize.

Comment: Not sure how much luck you're going to have with that. If your IP address changes, packets destined for your original IP will probably end up in the bitbucket. You may want to consider telling customer you don't support changing of the elusive device IP address - sometimes, non-tech solution are the best, they're certainly easy to implement :-)

Comment: I've tried to reason with my project lead to no avail.  The SOP for the box is to always change the IP, even though I cannot think of a single use-case where this would provide any benefit.  I forgot to state that each one of my sockets are transmitting UDP.  The only receiving being done is via Multicast, or there are additional handshaking routines that occur.

Comment: Okay then, how about a proxy box with two NICs. One talking to your embedded box with an unchanging NIC, the other adapting to the elusive box. It just runs forwarding software for the link. I know that's getting complicated but, if they're going to impose these limitations, you may have to think "outside the boxes". Bottom line here, without two NICs, I don't think you can both adapt _and_ maintain current connections.

Comment: While that certainly would work, the customer doesn't want any more hardware.  I've been down a wide variety of these roads myself to no avail.  I keep getting push back.  Also, what I find rather frustrating is that despite the embedded box having SSH capability, the assumption is that the user isn't well trained enough to SSH into the Linux host and change the IP.  Basically, from what I've gathered, they are blindly following a checklist and "Step 1" is "Change IP of Box, thus breaking everything."

Comment: While quite ugly, it probably would be possible to hack a custom IP stack which would always claim to the oddball box that the embedded system was on whatever subnet the oddball felt like being on, while staying at a consistent address as far as everyone else is concerned.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas guys.  As far as I know, the "best" option seems to be to just hack together a interfaces file and then call command a system restart from the program.  Hacky I know, but it won't take long to implement and the user will be unable to use the system for about a minute or so during the reboot, which should be ok.  I absolutely hate being put into situations where I'm forced to hack something like this together, but it looks like I have no alternative... :(

Comment: Are you sure you really need to boot the box the have the network set up diffently? This isn't windows, is it? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to *change* the IP address of the interface, you want to add an additional IP address and subnet to the interface. Search your Linux system documentation for [IP Alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing) functionality.

[Here's the HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/IP-Alias.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks promising.  Is there an cleaner implementation in C/C++ than just calling system() on the command line commands?

Comment: You can look at iproute2 to figure out how it interfaces to the kernel, but I'm going to guess that `system("ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 brd + dev eth0")` will be a lot easier - and more maintainable - in the long run.